# Moving or creating many product variations

Tags: 7, commerce

Problem:
many, many product variations.  Think of it as a product configuration tool to customize your item.

I tried this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc

It did create variations, however there seems to be some issue where they exist only as variations,  they don't get attached to a product (if that makes sense).  Basically, I can only see them under the admin list of variations.

Question 1: What's the most effective way to auto-generate many variations of a product?

Question 2: Can I somehow attach these variations to a product now that they're generated? Happy to do this directly in the database and/or create a standalone script to do so.

I may very well be missing something obvious, this "many variations" problem must be quite common.

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1:

until some awesome person posts a different answer, I'm afraid the answer to this is to use "commerce_bpc" to generate all your variations, and then attach your variations to the product by writing a standalone script.  See below.

## Question 2:

you can attach variations to a product after they've been created with "commerce_bpc".

field_data_field_product is the table that links variations to products.

Adding new rows where "field_product_product_id" is the variation you want to attach to a product will attach the variation to the product.

also,  add the same row to:  field_revision_field_product and clear cache.